Why is the request URL / HTTP_REFERRER in Django error from an external domain?
TL;DR
Was getting a Django error because I wasn't properly redirecting authenticated users making GET requests to my login endpoint (fixed this problem); however, I'd like to understand why the Request URL / HTTP_REFERRER in the error message was an external domain.
Background
I've been getting a few Django server errors per month in my production web app that list sendgrid.net as the Request URL (as well as the HTTP_REFERRER). I realized that some of my transactional email templates were turning links into strange sendgrid URLs for clicktracking, so I added clicktracking="off" to all the anchor elements in my templates to avoid this. However, the errors have persisted.
Current Problem
Today I tried navigating to https://example.com/login/ when I was already logged in, expecting it to redirect me to my user profile page but instead it triggered a 500 error. When I looked at the error readout that was automatically emailed to me from my Django app, the Request URL / HTTP_REFERRER was not https://example.com/login/ but rather a subdomain of sendgrid.net (see below).
The error was being triggered on my view called CustomLoginView:
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /login/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'member-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['member/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']
Raised during: home.views.CustomLoginView
Request information:
USER: Doe, John: john.doe@example.com

The Sendgrid Request URL
The URL is structured like this: https://u<8-digit ID number>.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=<extremely long string of characters>.
views.py
Note that the view did not have redirect_authenticated_user = True before (which was causing the error). I added that line to fix the error.
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    """
    need custom login so I can set session timezone upon login
    """
    redirect_authenticated_user = True  # This is what I added to fix 500 server error

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Security check complete. Log the user in."""
        auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
        # now set session timezone according to user's preference
        tzname = self.request.user.tz_preference.key
        self.request.session["django_timezone"] = tzname
        # and activate it (after this view, middleware will activate it)
        timezone.activate(zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(tzname))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

What is the cause?
The way I see it, there are two problems here:

My CustomLoginView is not properly redirecting already-logged-in users to their dashboard when a GET request is made to CustomLoginView.
Somehow, Sendgrid is involved in a way I cannot begin to understand. How can this subdomain of Sendgrid be hijacking a request to my domain?

I fixed problem number one by setting redirect_authenticated_user = True on my CustomLoginView, but I can't figure out why the Request URL / HTTP_REFERRER were from this Sendgrid subdomain.
Things I tried
I noticed I still had three DNS records having to do with Sendgrid, so I deleted those, but the error is still persisting.
Other potentially relevant info
I'm using NGINX and Gunicorn to serve my application
First part of error readout
Internal Server Error: /login/

NoReverseMatch at /login/
Reverse for 'user-detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']

Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://u<8-digit ID number>.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=<extremely long string of characters>
Django Version: 5.0.6
Python Executable: /example/path/venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.10.12
Python Path: ['/example/path/', '/example/path/venv/bin', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/example/path/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
Server time: Fri, 06 Dec 2024 08:45:04 -0700
HTTP_REFERER = 'https://u<8-digit ID number>.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=<extremely long string of characters>
...


What exactly do you mean when you say "Request URL"? Where exactly do you see this? Can you share the output you're looking at (masking the actual URL if needed)?

Are you perhaps using Sendgrid for sending emails via your app? And have sendgrid configured for click tracking? And you hit the login page from a link via email?

@AbdulAzizBarkat I added the first part of the error message so you can see where Request URL fits into the error message. I disabled click tracking on Sendgrid a long time ago, and the error occured when typing the URL straight into the address bar of the browser (i.e., it wasn't tied to clicking a link within a sendgrid-generated email).

We don't have enough information to answer this. Here's some guesses: 1) You previously had some sort of permanent redirects set up for your site and the browser is still following those (You can try from a different browser / incognito mode to see if that works). 2) You have some misconfiguration in either Nginx or some other layer where you're using the wrong hostname.
